# is it bad form to mix url popovers with url modals?

Tags: gui-design

I was just curious if there are any rules around mixing url popovers with url modals?  For example, there may be a few urls in the footer.  A "Terms and Conditions" url may be used to display a lengthy page of terms and conditions.  Therefore, a modal containing a dedicated page would be appropriate for this.  However, a "Support" url may just display an email address and phone number so a popover may be appropriate for this.

Different display implementations may be appropriate for these 2 different pieces of information.  However, are there any rules about using these 2 alternate display implementations together from the same collection of urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modals and popovers are used together all the time.

If you do decide to do this, it's good practice to:

- Ensure that the triggering elements do not look the same.
- Ensure that the rest of the interface is relatively calm as both modals and pop-ups are quite intrusive.

For example, if button opens the terms & conditions modal, then don't use a button for the support pop-up because your UX behavior becomes inconsistent.

Fortunately, there are lots of ways to design trigger widgets so you have plenty of choices.